# Limit facets and random count to value specified by user

Tags: random, solr, facet

**Using Solr 6.4**

When running a query over a set of documents I need to be able to return a random set of results that are limited to a number the customer requests.

e.g. The customer running the search wants 100 random documents from the 1,000,000 they have in their index.

Of course I could `&fq={!frange incu=false l=0 u=1}mod(random_1927377943, 1)&pageSize=100`... problem solved.

Not really, because I also need the facets for the type of document they are searching for in their index.  However, the facets are related to the **numFound** which there could be any number found between 0-1,000,000.

```
"response":{"numFound":1000000,"start":0,"docs":[]
  },
  "facet_counts":{
    "facet_queries":{},
    "facet_fields":{
      "documentTypeId":[
        "78",500000,
        "3",250000,
        "2",150000,
        "1",100000,
```

How do I limit the random numFound results to the specific number the customer is asking for (100) AND where the facets of each **documentTypeId** reflect the total the number of random results the customer is requesting?

```
"response":{"numFound":100,"start":0,"docs":[]
  },
  "facet_counts":{
    "facet_queries":{},
    "facet_fields":{
      "documentTypeId":[
        "78",50,
        "3",25,
        "2",15,
        "1",10,
```

Comment: Fetch the random documents first, then use those ids for a second query to get the proper facets?

Comment: Unfortunately, that is where I am heading. Seems like there should be a LIMIT mechanism.